# Anime (maybe movie) about a boy meets naked girl with a very distinct thick collar or bracelet

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I’m trying to find an anime I saw on Mangas Channel in Hotbird Satellite before 2006, I think it was a trailer.

I remember watching a boy in the street that notices a young girl (she could be an alien or an angel) walking naked with a thick bracelet on her wrist or maybe it was a collar on her neck, definitely had an inscription on it that sort of looked like a triangle if I remember well and I also remember him saving her from being hit by a truck.

Comment: @DavidW - To clarify i only watched the trailer as a kid and that was between 2005-2007. i tried to minimize the details to the ones i am only fairly certain of , my memories of her being not normal or not human and how she appeared in front of him are fuzzy that is why i didn't include them at first. Though i probably should've included that when she kisses him something sci-fi-ish happens but since i couldn't remember exactly or even vaguely what it was i decided against including it in my question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is  [DearS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DearS#Anime). The main character saves a collar-wearing naked (alien) girl from a truck in the first episode.

Comment: Hi, it looks like it. The marks on her forehead looks familiar and also the scene where he saves her from the truck and she kisses him looks similar to what i remember , although the collar on her neck doesn't look at all like i remember(i remember it being metallic and black or dark blue and maybe hexagonal in shape) thanks for taking your time to answer my question.